# Proof verification of decomposition of abelian group into torsion and free groups

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, abelian-groups, torsion-groups, free-abelian-group

**Claim**: Let $A$ be a (not necessarily f.g.) abelian group. Suppose that $T$ is the subgroup of all torsion elements in $A$, and we have that:

$${A}\diagup{T} \cong F$$

where $F$ is a free abelian group. Then:

$$A \cong A \diagup T \oplus F$$

**Proof** (edited after answer from elemelons)

By the definition of quotient groups, there exists a (set-theoretic) section $s : F \to A$ such that $A = \{s(f) + t : f \in F, t \in T\}$ as a set, where $s$ maps an element $f \in F$ to $a \in A$ such that its coset is $a+T \in A \diagup T$ under the assumed isomorphism.

We claim that there exists a section $s_*$ which is also an injective homomorphism. Let $B = \{f_i\}_I$ be a (not necessarily finite) basis for $F$. Then, we define our section as follows:

$$s_* : F \to A, f  \mapsto \sum_{i=1}^N n_i s(f_i)$$

where $f = \sum_{i=1}^N n_i f_i$ for $f_i \in B$, and $s$ is the arbitrary section previously asserted to exist. This is clearly a homomorphism. Suppose that:

$$f = \sum_{i=1}^N n_i f_i, \;\; s_*(f) = \sum_{i=1}^N n_i s(f_i) = 0$$

Then:

$$\sum_{i=1}^N n_i (a_i + T) = 0 + T$$

But from the isomorphism , we know that $A \diagup T$ is free, with $(a_i + T)_I$ forming a basis. Hence, we must have $n_i \equiv 0$.

$$\implies f = 0$$

Thus, $s_*$ is injective. We now consider:

$$A = \{ f + t : f \in F^*, t \in T \}$$

where $F^* := s_*(F) \le A$. Note that $F^* \cong F$, so it is free.

It suffices to show that this sum is direct. Let $f_1, f_2 \in F^*$, $t_1,t_2 \in T$, and suppose that:

$$f_1 + t_1 = f_2 + t_2$$

$$\implies f_1 - f_2 = t_2 - t_1$$

Then, the LHS is an element of a free group, and the RHS is an element of a torsion group. Thus, both must be equal to $0$. Result follows.

**Question**: Is this proof correct? This all seems quite simple, but I would like to make sure there are no inaccuracies. This result superficially seems to contradict other results (for instance, it is known that not every non-f.g. abelian group can be decomposed in this way), but note that a lot is assumed in the premise of the question.

There are lots of questions on similar topics, but I haven't found a duplicate anywhere.

Comment: Almost there. Don't say $A$ is free (it's not), or refer to $a_i+T$ as an element of $A$ (it's not; it's an element of $A/T$). Instead, to go from $s_*(f)=0$ to $f=0$, simply apply the projection $A\to A/T\cong F$ to both sides; the projection, by definition, undoes the section (i.e. the section is a "right inverse" for the projection). | Also, I am now a bit iffy about using the term "section"; for the categorical-minded, we are in the category of groups unless told otherwise, so "section" by itself suggests homomorphism. I suppose I recommend saying "set-theoretic section" where appropriate.

Comment: @elemelons Thanks for the help. That was just a typo. Does the argument not work taking place in $A \diagup T$?

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean. That's right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You refer to elements of $F$ as if they are elements of $A$. But this is not so: there is an isomorphism $A/T\cong F$, so we may identify elements of $F$ with *cosets* of $T$. We may pick a *coset representative* $a(f)$ for each such coset, which is essentially a function $a:F\to A$. (We call $a$ a *section* of the projection $A\to A/T$.) In general, this will not be a homomorphism, so will only identify $F$ with a subset of $A$, not a subgroup. Indeed, without our hypotheses (i.e. $F$ is free), there is *no* set-theoretic section which is a homomorphism.

To use the hypothesis that $F$ is free, pick a basis for it, pick coset representatives for the basis elements, then "extend linearly" for a section $a:F\to A$ which is indeed additive (and one-to-one; check this). This identifies $F$ with a free subgroup of $A$, and then your proof basically applies at that point.

Comment: Thanks for the answer; I wasn't aware of the terminology of sections. I agree that $F \not \subseteq A$. I couldn't think of how to phrase it, so I elided it, believing it to only be a minor complication. But as you have pointed out, I also need the additive structure to be preserved in some way, so my proof was not really correct. I have updated the proof bearing in mind your remarks. Would you mind confirming that it is now correct?