# Decomposition of infinite abelian groups

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, infinite-groups, torsion-groups

A colleague recently mentioned a "Prüfer Decomposition Theorem", claiming that every abelian group $A$ could be expressed as the direct sum $A = T(A) \oplus F(A)$, where $T(A)$ is the torsion subgroup and $F(A)$ is the torsion-free subgroup (=A/T).  Is this true?

I realize that unlike [finite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abelian_group#Classification) abelian groups, the classification of abelian groups is unfinished ([as others note](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/313737/status-of-the-classification-of-non-finitely-generated-abelian-groups)).

And while this decomposition easily holds for *finitely generated* abelian groups (which [decompose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finitely_generated_abelian_group) like $A=\mathbb {Z} ^{n}\oplus \mathbb {Z} /q_{1}\mathbb {Z} \oplus \cdots \oplus \mathbb {Z} /q_{t}\mathbb {Z}$), and for divisible groups (which [decompose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisible_group#Structure_theorem_of_divisible_groups) to $A=\left(\bigoplus_{p\in {\mathbf {P} }}{\mathbb {Z} }[p^{\infty }]^{(I_{p})}\right)\oplus {\mathbb {Q} }^{(I)}$ ), [Wikipedia at least](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torsion_subgroup) claims it does not hold generally.

However, [a recent question asked about verifying a proof of this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4690839/proof-verification-of-decomposition-of-abelian-group-into-torsion-and-free-group), so I am suspicious.

Also, absent a complete classification, what can we say about the sorts of things A/T may be?  For example, a torsion-free abelian group of finite rank $r$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb{Q}_r$, and there are also the p-adic integers $\mathbb{Z}_p$ of infinite rank.

Comment: Note that the question you link to has the added assumption that $A/T$ is a free abelian group.

Answer (score 6):

The linked question has an important additional assumption: that $A/T$ is free. In fact given a short exact sequence

$$0\to T\to A\to F\to 0$$

with $F$ free, we have that $A\simeq T\oplus F$. Regardless of what those groups are.

> Is this true?

Your colleague is unfortunately wrong.

The counterexample is as follows: $A=\prod \mathbb{Z}_p$ over the set of all primes. Then $T(A)=\bigoplus\mathbb{Z}_p$. But there is no subgroup of $A$ isomorphic to $A/T(A)$. Because [$A/T(A)$ is divisible](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9996/frac-prod-mathbbz-p-bigoplus-mathbbz-p-is-a-divisible-abelian-group) (and nontrivial). However the equation $px=C$ has no solution in $A$, if $p$ is prime and $C$ has non-zero $p$-th coordinate.